# Superimposed images flicker when changing width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making an image comparison feature. It's working fairly well, except that the images flicker when the front (blue) image is changing width. It appears to be some sort of issue with `z-index`?

Behavior differs slightly depending on browser used:

- **Safari**: flickers a bit
- **Chrome**: flickers a lot
- **Firefox**: shows the green image at all times

```js
const $imageSlider = document.querySelector(".image-slider");
const $sliderHandle = $imageSlider.querySelector(".image-slider__handle");
const $container = $imageSlider.querySelector(".image-slider__container--left");

const handleMouseMove = event => {
  const sliderPosition = `${(event.offsetX / $imageSlider.offsetWidth) * 100}%`;
  $container.style.width = sliderPosition;
  $sliderHandle.style.left = sliderPosition;
};

$imageSlider.addEventListener("mousemove", event =>
  requestAnimationFrame(() => handleMouseMove(event))
);
```

```css
.image-slider {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.image-slider__handle {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 0.25rem;
  background-color: white;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.image-slider__container {
  height: 100%;
}

.image-slider__container--left {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-slider__image {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p>Move the mouse across the surface below to compare images:</p>

<div class="image-slider">
  <div class="image-slider__container image-slider__container--left">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200/0000FF/808080?text=Lorem" class="image-slider__image" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="image-slider__container image-slider__container--right">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400/00FF00/808080?text=Ipsum" class="image-slider__image" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="image-slider__handle"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: When moving the mouse very gently just a bit to the right/left the blue image disappears completely..

Comment: @iLuvLogix Yes, that happens too.

Comment: it works better if you don't format your string then check `if (sliderPosition > 1)`, if that passes then format and set your style values. Like [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/m0czdyv6/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flickering is caused by affecting the "hoveredness" of the image slider *in logic that runs upon hover*. Hovering the slider moves the handle under the mouse, and the handle now intercepts the hover event, causing further hovers to have their offset values calculated relative to the handle, not the slider. And as soon as the mouse moves off the handle, it again correctly causes a `mousemove` event on the slider.

This is easily fixed by applying `pointer-events: none` to all elements which may block (and intercept) the pointer event.

Pardon the change in convention - I renamed some of the classes for myself.

```js
const imageSlider = document.querySelector('.slider');
const sliderHandle = imageSlider.querySelector('.handle');
const container = imageSlider.querySelector('.pane.left');

imageSlider.addEventListener('mousemove', event => {
  const sliderPosition = `${(event.offsetX / imageSlider.offsetWidth) * 100}%`;
  container.style.width = sliderPosition;
  sliderHandle.style.left = sliderPosition;
});
```

```css
.slider {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.slider > .handle {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 0.25rem;
  background-color: white;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  pointer-events: none; /* Don't block mouse events to .slider! */
}

.slider > .pane {
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none; /* Don't block mouse events to .slider! */
}

.slider > .pane.left {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider > .pane > img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p>Move the mouse across the surface below to compare images:</p>

<div class="slider">
  <div class="pane left">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200/0000FF/808080?text=Lorem" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="pane right">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400/00FF00/808080?text=Ipsum" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="handle"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: While [conventions](http://getbem.com) can be argued back and forth, the fix itself is the most suitable, even if the other answers and comments also have been very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Aha thanks for the link to BEM! Now I see there is method to the madness.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider an easier way using multiple background and less of code. By using `background-clip` and `content-box` I can adjust the visible part by increasing decreasing the padding:

```js
const $imageSlider = document.querySelector(".image-slider");

const handleMouseMove = event => {
  $imageSlider.style.paddingLeft = event.offsetX+"px";
};

$imageSlider.addEventListener("mousemove", event =>
  requestAnimationFrame(() => handleMouseMove(event))
);
```

```css
.image-slider {
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  background:
    /*a white line(width:4px height:100%) positionned on the left of the content-box*/
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) left/4px 100% content-box,
    /*the top image a the center clipped to the content-box but positionned relatively to the padding-box*/
    url(https://via.placeholder.com/200/0000FF/808080?text=Lorem) center/cover padding-box content-box,
    url(https://via.placeholder.com/200/00FF00/808080?text=Ipsum) center/cover;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<p>Move the mouse across the surface below to compare images:</p>

<div class="image-slider">
</div>
```